# Touching an animal in a gentle way

Tags: word-choice

What is the most appropriate phrase for touching i.e. a dog or a horse in a gentle manner? My first guesses are 'to pet' or 'to fondle' or 'to scratch'. Anyway, the other meanings of those words let me conclude, that there need to be more appropriate words.

Comment: **to pet** would be the most common term for that. Example: **Wow, is this your cat? Can I pet it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely **pet** or **stroke** your dog.
Though **pet** may have other connotations if applied to humans, it's perfectly acceptable to pet your pet.

**Scratch** is OK.
If you're going to scratch your dog's head, people are going to generally take that to being a gentle action - they really wouldn't assume without other context that you were about to attack him with barbed wire ;)

There's a diminutive form of **scratch** you could also use - **scritch**. You're probably not going to find it in any dictionary<sup>[1]</sup>, though I have a vague idea it may have originated in the Peanuts [Snoopy] comic strip.

You can also **pat** a dog or horse, though that diminishes with size. You wouldn't want to pat the cat, she wouldn't like it.

**Fondle** is *definitely* to be avoided.
That is really never going to give the right impression. It has only sexual overtones & no 'clean' alternative definition.

<sup>[1]</sup>No results in OALD but I found it in 
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scritch)

> US  [with object] To scratch; (now) especially to scratch (a pet)
>   affectionately with one's fingernails.

Comment: Yes, cats love scritches. :) It's interesting to note that we say scratch the cat's head or the dog's head, when the actual physical movement of the fingers is not the same as to scratch someone's face, for instance. Isn't that funny?

Comment: I would guess that's probably why it was 'diminutised' (I'm sure that's not a proper word;) to scritch. It has no aggressive connotation.

Comment: Indeed, if I scratch you (on purpose, sorry) I rake my nails over your skin. But, if I scratch a dog or cat's head, I actually move my nails or fingertips in short little movements. Yes,  I agree that scritch is a great verb. Oh, by the way,  no  one said Pat the dog's head. :)

Comment: I have pretty commonly seen ["fondle" used for stroking an animal's ears](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fondled+his+ears%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&oq=%22fondled+his+ears%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.2944j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (dogs, horses, probably not cats as they generally don't like that). I think specifying "ears" mitigates the sexual connotation.

Comment: Honestly, I think it would be best avoided by a non-native... just in case ;)

Comment: @Lambie - On the other hand, if I scratch your back (and you scratch mine), then it's back to a positive connotation again.

Answer (score 0):

“pet” and “stroke” are good words. “fondle” and “scratch” may be interpreted in a different manner